# Windows device driver don't start with parameter 0

Tags: c++, windows, driver

It's my first device driver for Windows and I followed the step-by-step instructions at http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/misc/writing_devicedriver.html but my device driver doesn't start at windows boot and also the event viewer shows an error and when I click on the error in the event viewer the thing crashes. When I start the driver manually after windows boot it works. Is this tutorial incomplete? I already found the sources in the internet but not at this site and I think I found an error in his sources, too, he just forgot to add a header file to the "Writing Events from a Device Driver. I can compile it without any errors in DDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this tutorial is incomplete and very old. Install WDK and follow one of WDK samples, written using plain WDM, or better, KMDF. Driver installation should be done using .inf file, and not by manual Registry editing.

If you still want to know why this driver doesn't start, debug it. Possibly its DriverEntry or CreateCamel function fail from some reason.

Another thing you can do without debugging, is to add a lot of KdPrint statements to the driver, and watch them using WinDbg, or DebugView.

Comment: I think it's the "Writing events from the driver" because it gives me error in event viewer, too. Do you have another advise how to solve this? What message do I get in the event viewer when it works?

Comment: You need to debug the driver - there is no another way. So, decide whether you want to make full remote debugging with WinDbg, ir "light" trace debugging using DbgView. See details in DbgView help, Logging at Boot Time.

Comment: I can log at boot time with DbgView?

Comment: Yes, you can. Ensure that Capture Kernel is checked, and execute Capture - Log Boot command. Then reboot the computer.